# what is the probability a moving object located inside an n by n square area gets out of the area after time t

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Assume we have *n* by *n* square area and a movable object initially located at a random position in the specified area. If the object mobility modeled by a Gauss-Markov mobility model with a random speed(*S*) and a **random direction (*R*)**, what is the probability the object gets out of the area in time *t*?

**The Gauss-Markov mobility model Detail.**

The current speed and direction is related to the previous speed and direction as the following equation.

$S_{t} = \alpha S_{t−1} + (1−\alpha)\check{S} + (1−\alpha^2) \sqrt{S_{x_{t−1}}}$

$d_{t} = \alpha d_{t−1} + (1−\alpha)\check{d} + (1−\alpha^2) \sqrt{d_{x_{t−1}}}$

As $S_{t}$ and $d_{t}$ are values of speed and direction for movement in the period time t. $S_{t−1}$ and $d_{t−1}$ are values of speed and direction for movement in the period time t−1. α is a constant value in the range [0,1]. $\check{S}$ and $\check{d}$ are constants representing the mean speed and direction. $S_{x_{t−1}}$ and $d_{x_{t−l}}$ are random variables from a Gaussian distribution. α  is a single tuning parameter that represents the different levels of randomness or degree of random.

The destination position of the motion at time t is calculated by the following equations.

$x_{t}=x_{t−1} + x_{t-1}\cos{d_{t−1}}$

$y_{t} = y_{t−1} + S_{t−1}\sin{d_{t−1}}$

Comment: What is a Gauss-Markov mobility model? Please be more explicit.

Comment: Dear @DieterKadelka, thank you for your reply. In my wireless sensor simulator I use Gauss-Markov mobility model to move an object from place to place. This model calculates the speed and direction and the object moves with the calculated speed and direction. The current speed and direction is related to the previous speed and direction. I am not able to write the equations here. please check the following paper for more detail on the model.  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4141345

Comment: Sorry, the paper in the link is not freely accessible!

Comment: I came to know how to add equation lately. please check the edited version of the problem.  It is too long to reply in the comment section. thank you. @DieterKadelka